# Namespace error while importing Oracle HCM Data Loader in TIBCO bw6

Tags: oracle, tibco

I am importing the HCM Data Loader WSDL in TIBCO BW6. After importing the wsdl, one of the element is showing "message undefined" error.

The detailed error description as follows :

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
WSDL import error.  The WSDL with namespace [http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/errors/] imported by a WSDL is not found in the module or dependent modules.  Ensure the WSDL with this namespace exists in the module or dependent modules. Furthermore, if this WSDL is provided by a SharedModule then ensure it is contained in the folder [Service Descriptors] of the SharedModule.  HCMDataLoader.wsdl  /DEV_tester/Service Descriptors Unknown EMF Validation Problems

I found that the above namespace is defined in WSDL and also mentioned at  import element also.
So here what I should modify in the namespace, to resolve this error?

Comment: Can anyone please help me.

Comment: the error I am getting is as below :

The fault element is referencing an undefined message 'ServiceException'. Check that the message name and namespace are correct and that the message has been defined.